# Скрипт постоянно ожидающий команд и в то же время с запущенным вечным циклом

Tags: python, telegram, asyncio, python-3.5

У нас есть телеграм бот с методами

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def on_chat_message(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']
    full_name = msg['chat']['first_name'] + ' ' + msg['chat']['last_name']
    username = msg['chat']['username']
    print('User:', full_name, '\nNickname:', username, '\nGot command:', command)
    markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
        ['Check once'],
        ['Start autoinformer', 'Stop autoinformer']
    ])
    if command == '/start':
        yield from bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Choose option:', reply_markup=markup)
    elif command == 'Check once':
        yield from bot.sendMessage(chat_id, latest_build_number)
    elif command == 'Start autoinformer':
        stop_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[['Stop autoinformer']], resize_keyboard=True)
        yield from bot.sendMessage(chat_id, //TODO, reply_markup=stop_markup)
    elif command == 'Stop autoinformer':
        yield from bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Got you.'//TODO, reply_markup=markup)

def check_always(chat_id):
    global latest_build_number
    latest_build_number = check_build()
    print(latest_build_number)
    while 1:
        build_new = check_build()
        if latest_build_number == build_new:
            time.sleep(10)
        else:
            latest_build_number = build_new
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, latest_build_number)
```

Как мне реализовать возможность принимать новые сообщения методу on_chat_message(msg) и при этом, если получена команда Start autoinformer, начать крутить метод check_always(chat_id) до тех пор, пока не будет получена команда Stop autoinformer?

Comment: Не нужно весь код, который у вас есть приводить. Вместо этого, создайте минимальный (но полный) пример, который демонстрирует проблему ([mcve])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле все оказалось просто:

```
def on_chat_msg(msg):
    do_smth()

def cycle():
    while True:
        do_smth_else()

th = threading.Thread(target=cycle, args=[], daemon=True)
th.start()
```

Comment: У `asyncio` есть другие методы по исполнению нескольких вещей одновременно. Следует осторожно относится к созданию новых потоков.

Answer (score 0):

`MODE = [0]`

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def on_chat_message(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']
    full_name = msg['chat']['first_name'] + ' ' + msg['chat']['last_name']
    username = msg['chat']['username']
    print('User:', full_name, '\nNickname:', username, '\nGot command:', command)
    markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
        ['Check once'],
        ['Start autoinformer', 'Stop autoinformer']
    ])
    if command == '/start':
        yield from bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Choose option:', reply_markup=markup)
    elif command == 'Check once':
        yield from bot.sendMessage(chat_id, latest_build_number)

    elif command == 'Start autoinformer':
        stop_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[['Stop autoinformer']], resize_keyboard=True)

        MODE[0] = 1
        from threading import Thread
        Thread(target=check_always, args=(chat_id,)).start()

        yield from bot.sendMessage(chat_id, //TODO, reply_markup=stop_markup)

    elif command == 'Stop autoinformer':

        MODE[0] = 0

        yield from bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Got you.'//TODO, reply_markup=markup)

def check_always(chat_id):
    global latest_build_number
    latest_build_number = check_build()
    print(latest_build_number)

    while MODE[0]:

        build_new = check_build()
        if latest_build_number == build_new:
            time.sleep(10)
        else:
            latest_build_number = build_new
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, latest_build_number)
```

Comment: Старайтесь писать более развёрнутые ответы